# Is possible to have multi webbrowser logged in the same website but different credentials?

Tags: c#, vb.net

so... I have a form, for example with a TabControl.
At the click of a button, a tab is added with a panel inside, a second form is loaded into this panel containing a web browser.
The problem is that if on the first tab I log in to a website with an account, when I open the second tab, the second web browser is already logged in.

I "solved" this problem by having a second EXE loaded into the panel instead of a form.
But this thing is a bit intricate to get, besides the fact that I would be with 2 EXE (and I only need 1).
Moreover, when I click on the buttons of the second EXE in the panel, they simply don't work.

So I wonder. Is there a way to have multiple web browsers in the same EXE and log in to the same website with different accounts?
If not, how can I improve the current "2 EXE way"?

This is how i add the new tab with the new form:

```
Dim FrmPag As New Scheda
Dim Pagina As New TabPage("Nuova")
Dim PannelloPag As New Panel With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill, .Name = "PannelloCent"}
FrmPag.TopLevel = False
PannelloPag.Controls.Add(FrmPag)
Pagina.Controls.Add(PannelloPag)
FrmPag.Show()
TabControlCentrale.TabPages.Add(Pagina)
```

This is how i add the new tab with the other EXE:

```
Dim xx As New TestClass
xx.pnlForNotePad = Panel1
xx.Processo = "c:\another.exe"
xx.FormWithExe_Load(sender, e)

Class TestClass

    Public Property pnlForExe As Panel
    Public Property ExeProcess As Process
    Public Property Processo As String

    Public Sub FormWithNotePad_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim info As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo With {
            .UseShellExecute = True,
            .CreateNoWindow = True,
            .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
            .RedirectStandardInput = False,
            .RedirectStandardOutput = False,
            .RedirectStandardError = False,
            .FileName = Processo
        }
        ExeProcess = Process.Start(info)
        If ExeProcess Is Nothing Then Return
        ExeProcess.WaitForInputIdle()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        SetParent(ExeProcess.MainWindowHandle, pnlForExe.Handle)
        'SendMessage(ExeProcess.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0)'
        MoveWindow(ExeProcess.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, pnlForExe.Width, pnlForExe.Height, True)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The server knows you are already logged in by a cookie.  The cookie is obtained from the user temp folder.  So what you are asking is to stop the cookie from being sent so the server asks for a new login.

Comment: yes, but with multiple EXE in the main one, i can log in with different accounts without any problems. Works only when each webbrowser have his own process in the task manager.

Comment: Each instance of the webbrowser should be its own process when called from same app.